# How to make part of a code to run only once in perl

Tags: perl

How to make part of a code to run only once in perl "the first time it execute only" even if the script is executed many times later

Comment: As in, a subroutine that’s only effective once, or something that persists across program runs? And why?

Comment: show what kind of code you are talking about.  the best answer will be affected by that.

Comment: tongue in cheek answer: you can't; someone could run the script on a different computer and you would have no way of knowing.

Comment: @minitech as in only effective once sub

Comment: @ysth actually i was thinking of adding some copyright protection to the script to prevent it from being pirated or copied to other computers so i'm going to accept registration info from user on first run only or even better get cpu unique id and write it on external file only once and each time the script run it compare the current hardware id with the old very first run cpu id, because if writing it into variable or static string it will just be useless everytime it runs, what do you think of this idea?

Comment: I think it, like all DRM, sucks.  Enforce legal restrictions with legal means, not with irritations that make assumptions about the environment perfectly legitimate users want to use (e.g. moving a hard drive into a new computer, or installing and running the script from a thumb drive).  Just my opinion, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would develop a class object to do it with very clear English as to what it was doing.  In Ubuntu, create a new directory for your script under /var/run/[run_name]/ and on the first run make a file there using the script.  For instance:

File name: RunOnce.pm

```
package RunOnce;
use Moose;

has 'run_name' => ( is => 'ro' , isa => 'Str' , required => 1 );
has 'initialize_file' => ( is => 'ro' , isa => 'Str'
    , builder => '_build_initialize_file'
    , lazy => 1 );

sub _build_initialize_file {
    return '/var/run/'. $_[0]->run_name . '/run_once.txt';
}

sub is_initialized {
    my $self = shift;
    return ( -f $self->initialize_file );
}

sub initialize {
    my $self = shift;
    open(my $init_file,'>' . $self->initialize_file )
         || die "Could not open initialize file "
            . $self->initialize_file . "! $!";
    $self->process_initial_run();
    print $init_file "Initialized on " . localtime(time) . "\n";
    close($init_file);
}

sub process_initial_run {
    warn "I don't do anything yet.";
}

package main;

my $runner = RunOnce->new(run_name => 'test_run');
$runner->initialize unless $runner->is_initialized();

1;
```

I just tested this on my own box:

```
paul@paul-1204-virtualbox:~$ sudo rm -rf /var/run/test_run/
paul@paul-1204-virtualbox:~$ sudo mkdir /var/run/test_run/
paul@paul-1204-virtualbox:~$ sudo chown paul:paul /var/run/test_run
paul@paul-1204-virtualbox:~$ perl RunOnce.pm
I don't do anything yet. at RunOnce.pm line 29.
paul@paul-1204-virtualbox:~$ perl RunOnce.pm
paul@paul-1204-virtualbox:~$
```

Now you can override the package and class and do what you want and be able to use this multiple times with different items, without too much work:

New file, RunOnceOverride.pm:

```
package RunOnceOverride;

use Moose;

extends 'RunOnce';

sub process_initial_run {
    warn "I'm going to try to do something else!";
}

package main;

my $runner = RunOnceOverride->new(run_name => 'test_run_override');
$runner->initialize unless $runner->is_initialized();

1;
```

And now:

```
paul@paul-1204-virtualbox:~$ sudo rm -rf /var/run/test_run_override/
paul@paul-1204-virtualbox:~$ sudo mkdir /var/run/test_run_override/
paul@paul-1204-virtualbox:~$ sudo chown paul:paul /var/run/test_run_override/
paul@paul-1204-virtualbox:~$ perl -I. RunOnceOverride.pm
I'm going to try to do something else! at RunOnceOverride.pm line 8.
paul@paul-1204-virtualbox:~$ perl -I. RunOnceOverride.pm
paul@paul-1204-virtualbox:~$
```

That's a nice extendable solution to the problem, but initialize should probably check for is_initialized itself rather than expecting the main code to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can put that part of your code within some `if` block that tests, for example using a file, whether it is the first execution of the script or not and only executes the block if so.

Answer (score 2):

One possible way to do it is to rewrite the script itself, something like this:

```
use warnings;
use script;

#### RUN ONCE BEGIN

do_something_once_only();

my $script_name = $0;
my $script_copy = $0 . 'old';
open my $fin, '<', $script_name or die $!;
open my $fout, '>', $script_copy or die $!;

my $script_content = do { local $/ = undef; <$fin>; };
$script_content =~ s/#### RUN ONCE BEGIN.+?#### RUN ONCE END/s;
print $fout $script_content;
`cp $script_copy $script_name`;

#### RUN ONCE END

do_something_else();
```

It's a concept only; unfortunately, can't test it here. But basic idea is very simple: you make a clearly delimited 'run-once' block in your script, then, while executing it first time, remove this block from the script's content.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you do something like this:

```
mySub if (!(-e "/some/path/cpuid.txt"));

sub mySub() {
    //do something
    open(my $cpuid, ">", "/some/path/cpuid.txt") || die $!;
    print $cpuid "blah";
}
```

Btw, I am not a big fan of DRM in any form. Plus the way you are proposing to do this is going to be quite easy to break. Just delete the cpuid.txt file and you are golden.